# Square root of non-symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.

Tags: matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a $d \times d$ square positive semi-definite, **not necessarily symmetric**, real matrix in the sense that $v^TAv\ge 0$ for any vector $v\in\mathbb R^d$. How to show that there exists $B$ such that $$A=B^TB?$$

If $A$ is symmetric, this is easy to construct such $B$ by considering eigendecomposition.
What about the non-symmetric

---

---

**Edit**: Such $A$ is necessarrily symmetric, so how about changing the question to the existence of $B$ such that $$A=B^2$$?

Comment: If $A$ is not symmetric, then such a $B$ never exists, because $B^TB$ is symmetric.

Comment: the question is ambiguous, do you want to prove the existence of the square root or of the particular decomposition ?

Answer (score 1):

If $A = B^TB$ then $A^T = B^T B^{TT} = B^T B = A$ so then $A$ is symmetric, so it can't be done.

edit:  wikipedia has an [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_Jordan_decomposition) for the $A = B^2$ version of the question.

Comment: Oh yes, can you please look at the edit?